# Scenes of helicopter

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, helicopter, inspiration

Hi everyone,

I'm looking for scenes of helicopter on animated movie or movie. 
I would try the synthesis of this. So I need to impregnate the sounds with several scenes, several views, several sounds .....

Any exemples? Tips?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The one that immediately spring to mind is Apocalypse Now.  Walter Murch used helicpotor recordings, but also synthesised elements of helicopter sound. He then mixed between the acoustic and synthesised sounds, particularly in the dream like sequences.  IMO worth a look and evaluation.

http://www.salon.com/2000/04/27/murch/

Answer (score 1):

Hi lili

Sounds for a cool job, helicopters makes fun.
As bit depth said before, try to separate blades from engine. If you need fx for the blades, use a kind of pitched down sword-swishes or whooshes. Try to experiment with the pitch to find something who works. Also helicopters makes some great noise if they are in distant and there is only the low swapping sounds from the blades. Similar than: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffectstracksheet.php?prodid=90026
More helicopter sounds you can find: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffects/sound-effects-categories/sound-effects-helicopter.php

If you need helicopter sounds, I can make you a package up from $50 to $...

As an inspiration, the 80 tv series Airwolve came in my mind

Best

Guido

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short answer, but perspective is key, here.

Try to get many different perspectives so that the camera cuts are made more interesting and sonically different so that it doesn't sound like a plopped long helicopter sound was thrown in.

Good examples of wonderful helicopter design:

Black Hawk Down - cliche good helicopter movie

A good day to Die Hard (most recent movie - not sure if that is the "official" title or not)

Mission Impossible 1 (helicopter and train scene at the end)

Day After Tomorrow (helicopter crash scene, which also on the DVD has a special feature with a breakdown of the stems)

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

Thanks for all. Your examples are great. So I found what I wanted. Many scenes with different views and sounds. 
That's true that for a good chase with helicopter, we have to have sounds very differents to each plans. 
So I have the intention to use synthetic sounds and real sounds, as Apocalypse now.

Thanks for your help

Lili

Ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

To get the sense of movement from the helicopter (if you are using synthesized sounds, they will probably start out feeling motionless) adding doppler effects can be really fun!  There are various plugins that can do this including at least one for free:

http://www.vst4free.com/free_vst.php?plugin=ADopplerEn&id=517

I have heard helicopter sounds made from a noise source and an automated filter producing that distinctive envelope...not as realistic an effect on its own but can be cool sounding.